# How to change the response status code for successful operation in Swagger?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0, springfox

As shown in the image, it says "Response Class (Status 200)" for the add operation. However, the add operation has been implemented in such a way that it will never return 200. It returns 201 on success.

My question is how can I change the (Status 200) to (Status 201)?
The code for this part is as follows:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.PUT, value = "/add")
@ApiOperation(value = "Creates a new person", code = 201)
@ApiResponses(value = {
        @ApiResponse(code = 201, message = "Record created successfully"),
        @ApiResponse(code = 409, message = "ID already taken")
})
public ResponseEntity<String> add(@RequestParam(value = "name", required = true) String name,
        @RequestParam(value = "id", required = true) String id) {
    if (PD.searchByID(id).size() == 0) {
        Person p = new Person(name, id);
        PD.addPerson(p);
        System.out.println("Person added.");
        return new ResponseEntity<String>(HttpStatus.CREATED);
    } else {
        System.out.println("ID already taken.");
        return new ResponseEntity<String>(HttpStatus.CONFLICT);
    }
}
```

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Have you tried adding `@ResponseStatus` annotation to the operation?

Comment: @DilipKrishnan: you are a lifesaver!!!

Comment: @DilipKrishnan if you make that an answer rather than a comment, I will upvote it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the `@ResponseStatus` annotation to any a controller method to define the http status it should return. Ex

Adding the following annotation on acontroller method:

```
@ResponseStatus(code = HttpStatus.CREATED)
```

Will return a HTTP status 201 (Created)

Answer (score -1):

Adding the following annotation in controller method (method = requestMethod.PUT) or (method = requestMethod.POST) 
@ResponseStatus (code = HttpStatus.ACCEPTED)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Although it's good to post additional answers where you can add value, I don't think this answer adds anything that's not already included in the accepted answer, and arguably introduces an error because `HttpStatus.ACCEPTED` (i.e. 202) isn't the status that the question is talking about.